# Powershell script - placing an entry from infoblox WAPI into a spreadsheet

Tags: powershell, infobox

I want to use the following powershell code to iterate through a collection of IP addresses and check whether they have a DNS entry in InfoBlox.

```
Set-IBConfig -ProfileName 'MyGrid' -WAPIHost dns.xx.xxx -WAPIVersion latest - 
Credential (Get-Credential) -SkipCertificateCheck
$resultsFolder = "C:\Users\x\Documents\20220920"
$AviClusterList = 'C:\Users\x\Documents\20220920\AviCluster.csv'
$AviClusters = Import-csv $AviClusterList
foreach ($AviCluster in $AviClusters) {
    $AviClusterName = $AviCluster.FQDN
    $SEVirtualIPs = Import-Csv "$resultsFolder\$AviClusterName.csv"
    foreach($SEVirtualIP in $SEVirtualIPs){
         try {
         $ipObj = Get-IBObject -type ipv4address -filters 
   'status=USED',"ip_address=$($SEVirtualIP.'Service Engine Virtual IPs')"
    }
    catch {
    "A network was not found for this address"
    }
    $ipObj `
    | select ip_address `
    | Select-Object *,@{n="Infoblox Reservation Name";e={$ipObj.names}} `
    | Select-Object *,@{n="Status";e={$ipObj.status}} `
    | Select-Object *,@{n="In Conflict";e={$ipObj.is_conflict}} `
    | Export-csv -Path "$resultsFolder\AviVirtualIPReservations.csv" -append -NoTypeInformation -Force
    }
}
```

Currently I have `Catch` statement above.  I would like to get that `catch` statement added to the export CSV against the IP.  That way I know what IP reservation doesn't have a network.

Comment: Change `"A network was not found for this address"` to `$ipObj = @{ status = "A network was not found for this address" }`

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen that worked nearly as I had hoped. On the output CSV it inserts the comment as a separate row, I was hoping to append it to the end of the row. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "append it to the row"? Tagging it on the end after the last field would make your CSV not-a-CSV-anymore and you might run into issues with other CSV-parsing tools simply dropping the data completely on import

Comment: when I mean append to the end of the row, I should of been clearer and mean in a new column. So Column A is currently selected IP address, Column B is Reservation Name, Column C is Status, Column D is in Conflict, I would like the error message in Column E.

Comment: By the way you can continue a line with a `|` or a `,`.